# Double click of radio in IE

Tags: jquery, radio-button

HTML code:

```
<input value="YES" type="radio" disabled="disabled">
```

I have above line of code. The radio button is in disabled form.
In Internet Explorer, the double click works, even though its in disabled form.
This doesn't happen in firefox. How to prevent this in IE?
Is there any way in jQuery, through which I can prevent this?

Comment: the code line is ...?

Comment: "the double click works"? What do you mean by "work"?

Comment: works means, user is able to double click & select radio button, though it has disabled attribute.

Comment: What other javascript do you have loaded?  Radio buttons don't just start ignoring their "disabled" tag because you double-click them.

Answer (score 1):

The above issue is a React + IE bug.

This might help

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4457

Answer (score 0):

Hello to cancel the click:

```
<input value="YES" type="radio" disabled="disabled" onclick="return false;" ondblclick="return false;">
```

Comment: I tried using- ondblclick="return false;" But still on dbl click, the radio button is getting selected

Answer (score 0):

There's something you're not telling us.

Setting the disabled flag on a radio button will not allow the item to be selected--either by clicking or double clicking.

There must be something else loaded that is causing the double-click to set the value.  You need to look at your code and figure out where the "dblclick" event is called.  From there, it's going to be easier to fix.

To fix it, you'll need to change the dblclick function to check for whether the item is disabled. For example:

```
if ($(this).is(":disabled")) { 
    return false;
}
```

Adding that to the top of the function will prevent the code from being called.

<sub>(That makes a lot of presumptions, but again, there's something you're not telling us.)</sub>